# How to make JavaScript focus() work in IE of Windows CE 6.0 for input box

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-ce

I have been trying to make Javascript focus() work in Internet Explorer of Windows CE 6.0 for input box but it doesn't work. I have searched all over, tried different methods but it work very well in my desktop environment but doesn't work in IE of Windows CE 6.0.
I have already tried Motorola Enterprise browser, ZKBrowser for CE 6.0, without any luck.

Below is the method I tried:

```
var myTableDiv2 = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable2");
var table1 = document.createElement('TABLE');
table1.border = '1';
var tableBody2 = document.createElement('TBODY');
table1.appendChild(tableBody2);
var tr = document.createElement('TR');
tableBody1.appendChild(tr);
var input = document.createElement('input'); 
input.type = "text";   
input.setAttribute("size",'15');
input.setAttribute("value", '');
input.setAttribute("name", serial+'ItemCode');
input.setAttribute("autofocus",'True');
input.setAttribute("focus",'True');
input.onkeyup = function(){ValueChangedItem(this);};
var td = document.createElement('TD');
td.appendChild(input);
tr.appendChild(td);
myTableDiv2.appendChild(table1);

var inp = serial+'ItemCode';
var inputs = document.getElementsByName(inp);
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].name = serial+'ItemCode') {
    // alert(inputs[1].name);
    inputs[i].focus();
    inp.focus();
    break;
  }
}
```

Can anybody help me on this, I have been trying to figure it out but cannot, the below works very well on desktop.

Comment: I was trying it in Chrome and it works perfectly, just tried in IE 10 desktop, it doesn't work :-(

Comment: id' try to get it working on ie10 first as it might reverse fix ce 6.0. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535505/can-anyone-explain-why-focus-is-not-working-always-on-ie-10) and [this](http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/focus-is-not-working-in-ie-solution/) to see if they fix the issue

Comment: thanks @atmd, I got the solution by reading comments of http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/focus-is-not-working-in-ie-solution/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by the following code:

```
var inputs1 = document.getElementById(serial+'ItemCode');

inputs1.focus();
inputs1.focus();
inputs1.focus();
```

Comment: One more thing I would like to add up is that SetAttribute should also include id which will be the identifier.